# Is it possible to keep the search text in form after search is done?

Tags: html, flask, jinja2

After search result is shown on the same page below the form, I want the search term to still stay in the search box, not to be wiped out. My search form template:

```
<form class="search" method="post">

    <input name="query" type="text" style="max-width:700px" placeholder="Search over wbkg.." id="query" autocomplete="on" required>
    <button type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
    
    <input type="radio" name="options" id="kmatch" value="kmatch" checked="checked">match </input>
    <input type="radio" name="options" id="kextraction" value="kextraction"> extraction </input>
</form>
```

The flask view function:

```
@bp.route('/wbkg', methods=('GET', 'POST'))
def wbkg():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        query = request.form['query']
        search_type = request.form['options']

       results = search(query, search_type)
            
       return render_template('nlp/wbkg.html', items=results)

    return render_template('nlp/wbkg.html')
```

Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, just pass it back along with search results:

```
return render_template('nlp/wbkg.html', items=results, query=query)
```

And then display in template if it exists:

```
<input name="query" type="text" id="query" autocomplete="on" value="{{query}}" required>
```